# Variable not defined in subroutine after defined and made global

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

The following code gets an error as it says name 'Combo_Box Value' is not defined.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
import tkinter.font

class Pounds_Converter():
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.gui(parent)

def gui(self, parent):
    if parent == 0:
        self.w1 = Tk()
        self.w1.configure(bg = '#e4f3ff')
        self.w1.geometry('370x350')
    else:
        self.w1 = Frame(parent)
        self.w1.configure(bg = '#e4f3ff')
        self.w1.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 370, height = 350)
    self.label3 = Label(self.w1, text = "Pounds Converter", bg = "#e4f3ff", fg = "#002d5e", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Myanmar Text", size = 24), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.label3.place(x = 55, y = 50, width = 260, height = 62)
    self.label4 = Label(self.w1, text = "Pounds", bg = "#e4f3ff", fg = "#006fe8", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Myanmar Text", size = 12), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.label4.place(x = 60, y = 135, width = 60, height = 22)
    self.combo1 = Combobox(self.w1, font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Myanmar Text", size = 12), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.combo1.place(x = 250, y = 135, width = 76, height = 22)
    self.combo1['values'] = ("Dollars", "Euros")
    self.combo1.current(0)
    self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.Combo_Box)
    self.ltext3 = Entry(self.w1, bg = "#efffff", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "MS Shell Dlg 2", size = 8), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.ltext3.place(x = 20, y = 170, width = 140, height = 32)
    self.ltext3.insert(INSERT, "0.00")
    self.ltext4 = Entry(self.w1, bg = "#efffff", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "MS Shell Dlg 2", size = 8), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.ltext4.place(x = 220, y = 170, width = 140, height = 32)
    self.button2 = Button(self.w1, text = "Convert", bg = "#efffff", fg = "#006fe8", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "MS Shell Dlg 2", size = 8), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.button2.place(x = 120, y = 270, width = 130, height = 30)
    self.button2['command'] = self.Convert
    self.button3 = Button(self.w1, text = "Home", bg = "#e4f3ff", fg = "#006fe8", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Myanmar Text", size = 8), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
    self.button3.place(x = 20, y = 20, width = 40, height = 16)

def Combo_Box(self, e):
    Combo_Box_Value=self.combo1.get()
    return Combo_Box_Value


def Convert(self):
    global Combo_Box_Value
    Pounds=self.ltext3.get()
    Pounds = float(Pounds)
    if Combo_Box_Value== "Dollars":
        Dollars=Pounds*1.38
        self.ltext4.delete("0",END)
        self.ltext4.insert(INSERT,Dollars)
a = Pounds_Converter(0)
a.w1.mainloop()
```

That is the full code for that GUI widget. I would like to get the value of the combo box once it is changed then I need to use it in another variable.

Comment: Show more of your code and explain what it does?

Comment: If you really want to do it, add a 'global Combo_Box_Value' on the first line of your Bombo_Box function. Using global in a program is Not recommended, there is always a better way.

Comment: There is no need to use `global` when using functions in a class. Just change `Combo_Box_Value` to `self.Combo_Box_Value` That way, you can use it throughout the class. Of course, you may want to define it in the `__init__()` method as well, to further prevent this error.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin the self. the method does not work, how would I use this _init_()

Comment: @Fredericka what other ways could I do it

Comment: Now that i have the full code, i would suggest that in your __init__ method, you declare a attibute that has the name of your variable. Then you use it like a normal variable, but you add __self.__ in front of it.

Comment: You can create `__init__()` using `def __init__(self):`, and then adding any other code underneath, just as you would for a normal function. I don't understand why you are asking how to use `__init__()` if you are already using it in your code. Please be more clear on what you mean by the fact that the `self` method doesn't work. Are you getting error messages? Your methods don't have proper indentation; they all need to be _inside_ the class.

Comment: @Fredericka that leads to an error saying that there is no object combo1, how would I use this __init__() method

Comment: The code you posted has indentation errors.

Comment: Why don't you call `self.comb1.get()` inside `Convert()`? Then no global is required.

Answer (score 0):

> The following code gets an error as it says name 'Combo_Box Value' is
> not defined.

The problem can be fixed by changing `if Combo_Box_Value` to `if self.combo1.get()` on line 49. There's also no need to include a `global`.

Snippet:

```
def Convert(self):
    #global Combo_Box_Value
    Pounds=self.ltext3.get()
    Pounds = float(Pounds)
    if self.combo1.get()== "Dollars":
        Dollars=Pounds*1.38
        self.ltext4.delete("0",END)
        self.ltext4.insert(INSERT,Dollars)
```

Screenshot:

[image]